# libgdx- tilemap rendering problem

Tags: libgdx, tilemap

I don't really know how to describe my tilemap rendering problem with words, so I think the best way is to show the pictures.
This is how my map looks like when it rendered correctly: 
[image: Correct rendering]

but when I move the player little bit (the camera follows the player) I get this weird result:
[image: Bad rendering]

Notice how the tiles which generating the floor got this strange shape, like they are not align correctly.
I do have a padding in my tileset, so I'm not sure this is the problem.
I also tried to round the camera position to integers, but it's result was always rendered like the second picture (the unwanted way), instead of sometimes correctly and sometimes not.

What else can be the issue?

**EDIT:** I noticed now that this problem happened only when the camera reach to the edges points of the tilemap, and also right at the beginning of the program running (when the player is at his first position, before any movement was made).

Comment: How did you achieve the first image's result? Do you use different code for the first and second image?

Comment: It's the same code and even the same running. When the player is moving, sometimes it's look like the first result and sometimes like the second one.

Comment: Have you set the texture filter to nearest, nearest ? this is usually best for pixel art as it keeps the hard lines between colours.

Comment: I tried it also... the same result.